# RDLC Display a formatted Xml string

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, rdlc

I need to format my xml string to display it in RDLC report, arranged by tags. Something like

```
<Root>
  <Child>
     <SubChild>...</SubChild>
  </Child>
</Root>
```

I can't seem to find a way to do that, other than just iterating through the string horribly and trying to arrange it manually. Is there a way to do it with some format function in RDLC or in some other way and pass it to RDLC already formatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to format your XML strings outside RDLC.

You need to use `XMLWriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration` to save an indented XML without declaration line (i.e.: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`)

```
Dim strXML As String = "<Root><Child><SubChild>test</SubChild></Child></Root>"

Dim xmlDoc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
xmlDoc.LoadXml(strXML)

Dim xmlSettings As New System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
xmlSettings.Indent = True
xmlSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = True

Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder

Using writer As System.Xml.XmlWriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(sb, xmlSettings)
    xmlDoc.Save(writer)
End Using

MsgBox(sb.ToString())
```